# Change xml value in varous places that have the same tag

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I have a python script, that uses lxml to change the values of specific tags. I have the following xml

```
                    <gmd:CI_Citation>
                    <gmd:date>
                        <gmd:CI_Date>
                            <gmd:date>
                                <gco:Date>**1900-01-01**</gco:Date>
                            </gmd:date>
                            <gmd:dateType>
                                <gmd:CI_DateTypeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode" codeListValue="publication">Publication</gmd:CI_DateTypeCode>
                            </gmd:dateType>
                        </gmd:CI_Date>
                    </gmd:date>
                    <gmd:date>
                        <gmd:CI_Date>
                            <gmd:date>
                                <gco:Date>**1900-01-01**</gco:Date>
                            </gmd:date>
                            <gmd:dateType>
                                <gmd:CI_DateTypeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode" codeListValue="creation">Creation</gmd:CI_DateTypeCode>
                            </gmd:dateType>
                        </gmd:CI_Date>
                    </gmd:date>
                    <gmd:date>
                        <gmd:CI_Date>
                            <gmd:date>
                                <gco:Date>**1900-01-01**</gco:Date>
                            </gmd:date>
                            <gmd:dateType>
                                <gmd:CI_DateTypeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode" codeListValue="revision">Revision</gmd:CI_DateTypeCode>
                            </gmd:dateType>
                        </gmd:CI_Date>
                    </gmd:date>
                </gmd:CI_Citation>
```

For each different date type (Publication, Creation and Revision) I want to change the date to a specific date, however the tags for all 3 are the same  -

> ```
> //:gmd_citation/:gmd_CI:Citation/:gmd_date/:gmd_CI_Date/:gmd_date/:gco_Date
> ```

I am using the following function to change the values

```
def updateXMLTag (tag, value):
  xmlValue = root.xpath(tag)
  xmlValue[0].text = str(value)
```

What is the best way using xpath to get to the specific tag, so that the value can be changed?

Comment: The XML input is not well-formed because the  `gmd` and `gco` prefixes are not declared.

Comment: That is how the xml is. (though i have only posted a part of the xml document).

Comment: I have commented many times on XML questions, with any XML with namespaces (colon-separated prefixes), always include the root tag or wherever the namespace URI is defined (search for `xmlns=`). Please update the sample post.

Comment: @MapMan: You cannot take a part of an XML document and simply claim "That is how the xml is". What you have posted is not XML. lxml will choke on it. The namespaces and their prefixes may seem like a minor detail but they are there for a reason, like it or not.

Comment: I take your point, but wasn't sure if it was a good idea to post a 400 line xml document, hence why i only posted the relevant bits.

Comment: @MapMan did you check my edited answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my way of using xpath to get to the specific elements, and edit them:

```
# Find the best implementation available on the platform

try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO
except:
    from StringIO import StringIO

from lxml import etree

# proper namespaces added to get valid xml
xmlstr = StringIO("""<gmd:CI_Citation xmlns:gmd="http://gmd.example.com" xmlns:gco="http://gco.example.com">
        <gmd:date>
        <gmd:CI_Date>
            <gmd:date>
                <gco:Date>1900-01-01</gco:Date>
            </gmd:date>
            <gmd:dateType>
                <gmd:CI_DateTypeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode" codeListValue="publication">Publication</gmd:CI_DateTypeCode>
            </gmd:dateType>
        </gmd:CI_Date>
    </gmd:date>
    <gmd:date>
        <gmd:CI_Date>
            <gmd:date>
                <gco:Date>1900-01-01</gco:Date>
            </gmd:date>
            <gmd:dateType>
                <gmd:CI_DateTypeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode" codeListValue="creation">Creation</gmd:CI_DateTypeCode>
            </gmd:dateType>
        </gmd:CI_Date>
    </gmd:date>
    <gmd:date>
        <gmd:CI_Date>
            <gmd:date>
                <gco:Date>1900-01-01</gco:Date>
            </gmd:date>
        <gmd:dateType>
            <gmd:CI_DateTypeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode" codeListValue="revision">Revision</gmd:CI_DateTypeCode>
            </gmd:dateType>
        </gmd:CI_Date>
    </gmd:date>
</gmd:CI_Citation>""")

tree = etree.parse(xmlstr)
```

Here we use xpath to get all the (3) target elements.

```
targets = tree.xpath('/gmd:CI_Citation/gmd:date/gmd:CI_Date/gmd:dateType/gmd:CI_DateTypeCode', \
           namespaces={'gmd': "http://gmd.example.com", 'gco': "http://gco.example.com"})
```

The three elements are distinguished by unique attribute values,
which can be checked with a simple function `hasattr`

```
def hasattr(elem, att, val):
    try:
        return elem.attrib[att] == val
    except:
        return False
```

targets[0] codeListValue/ text node: "publication"/ "Publication"

targets[1] codeListValue/ text node: "creation"/ "Creation"

targets[2] codeListValue/ text node: "revision"/ "Revision"

Which one needs changes?

```
hasattr(targets[0], 'codeListValue', 'publication')  # True
hasattr(targets[1], 'codeListValue', 'creation')  # True
hasattr(targets[2], 'codeListValue', 'publication')  # False

# Let's change one of them
t1 = targets[1]
t1.text = 'New Creation'  # change text node

# and/or change attribute
t1.attrib['codeListValue'] = 'Latest Creation'
```

Finally, we save the result to a file

```
tree.write("output1.xml")
```

**Edit 1**

Here we navigate to cousin1 (gco:Date) of the already found target[1] that needs change:

```
t1 = targets[1]
parent1 = t1.getparent()
date1 = parent1.getprevious()
cousin1 = date1.getchildren()
len(cousin1)     #1
cousin1[0].text  #'1900-01-01'

# change the date
cousin1[0].text = '2017-5-3'
# again, write the result

tree.write("out456.xml")
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, however it does not change the gco:Date , which is what needs changing rather then the text of the codeListvalue.

Comment: @MapMan, I have edited my answer to show how to change the date.